# Facebook Commenting social plugin doesn't post to user's Facebook wall

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-wall

I've installed a Facebook commenting wall on a site for a client. It works without any hitches- except it doesn't post to the user's Facebook wall. I'm using the html5 version of the code that is included in the Comments Box plugin (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), and made sure that I'm loading the Javascript SDK as well. I'll attach the code I'm using to see if it helps.

Javascript SDK:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'my-id-here', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//url-here//channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional initialization code here
};
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
 </script>
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
```

Code where I want it to display:

```
<div class="facebookCommentWall column">
 <h3>Facebook Connect</h3>
 <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" data-num-posts="5" data-width="300" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

I'm not quite sure what's going wrong that it's not posting. I've looked through the forums exhaustively and there are people that are asking questions, but not quite the same as mine. Most want to do more than just post to the wall, I believe. And mine is quite simple, compared to that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Comments plugin is an inline comments area for your website.  It doesn't post anything to anyones wall.

**Edit**

You're right, you can have that comment appear on your own wall if you opt to check the box on the comment posting.

However, you have a bad DOM.

`<h3>Facebook Connect</h2>`

You have an opened H3 tag without any closing H3 tag.  This could be confusing the browser and able to properly render your information.

And it appears you've specified the fb-root DIV twice on your page.  The second calling of the getting of the SDK is not going to hurt, but it is extra.

Comment: I'd humbly disagree, unless I'm understanding this wrong. http://cl.ly/3v0m0R261j1V3r1y191p

Comment: Hi DMCS. Thanks for that- it's funny, I'd changed the h3/h2 issue on all other parts of the site- just forgot this page. Thanks for that. I also commented out the code in the footer, and just have it below the body tag. Unfortunately, it still doesn't do anything. Same problem; won't post to wall.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with your latest code examples?  Thank you.